# Как использовать переменную из метода в главном методе java?

Tags: java, переменные, методы

Доброго времени суток, друзья. Я только начинаю знакомиться с Java. И тут назрел вопрос. Есть, помимо главного метода, еще два. В одном из этих двух, есть переменная, которую мне необходимо использовать в другом методе, но он ее не видит, если просто написать, допустим 
`if (choice = 1) {
dir_kor();
}`
Может я как-то не так задал вопрос, вы уж простите, но думаю, что понятно
Прошу помочь)

```
`public class Battleship {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    choice_dir();
    if (dir = 1)
}
void choice_dir() {
    int rm_min = 1;
    int rm_max = 2;

    int dir = rm_min + (int) (Math.random() * rm_max);
}
```

}`

Comment: Не видит код где эта переменная определена. Не могли бы вы разместить весь код который необходим для понимания вопроса?

Comment: @Игорь Скоробогатько Не именуйте так переменные никогда. Соблюдайте [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут два варианта : вынести переменную как поле класса (например private int a) или передать ее через параметр метода, т.е. поменять немного сигнатуру метода.
Также, у Вас есть распространенная ошибка, у Вас в проверке = вместо == (= - это оператор присваивания, а == - оператор сравнения).
Поправьте меня, если я неправильно понял вопрос

Comment: `public class Battleship {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        choice_dir();
        if (dir = 1)
    }
        void choice_dir() {
        int rm_min = 1;
        int rm_max = 2;

        int dir = rm_min + (int) (Math.random() * rm_max);
        }
}`

Comment: Нужно чтобы я мог использовал переменную dir в других методах. Как быть?

Comment: лучше в вопрос вынесите этот код. Я же написал, либо вынести ее как поле, либо же через аргумент метода передавать

Comment: А кстати в вашем примере можно сделать просто : метод choice_dir будет вовзращать вычисляемое переменной dir значение. Тогда в main’e будет проверка if(choice_dir() == 1)

Answer (score 1):

Так будет проще всего:

```
public class Battleship {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int dir = choice_dir();
        if (dir == 1) {
            //doSomethig...
        }
    }

    int choice_dir() {
        int rm_min = 1;
        int rm_max = 2;
        return rm_min + (int) (Math.random() * rm_max);
    }
}
```

Как указывал @Ladence в `dir = 1` = нужно заменить на ==.